# App crashes when adding UICollectionView within a Nib file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building an experimentation app using the HMSegmentedControl framework. On this app I'm trying to add a UICollection view into a view made on a xib file, but I'm having trouble with it. The app crashes and I get this:

```
2016-02-01 10:23:40.693 SegmentControlExperimentation[1328:49671] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UICollectionView.m:3690
2016-02-01 10:23:40.699 SegmentControlExperimentation[1328:49671] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier MyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

I've been looking it up everywhere, but I couldn't come with a solution.
So I made a github repo and I cloned my code on this link: https://github.com/nascimentorafael/SegmentControlExperimentation
It is a really small and simple code. If one runs it, will get this crash. So have a look on the ViewController class and the view.xib.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: give your cell identifier name to xib.

Comment: I already did it! @KishoreKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I browsed your github repository and found you didn't practice UICollectionView in a right way. However, if you would like to avoid the crash only, just comment out codes line 102-105 & line 128 in your ViewController.m

If you would like to put have your collectionView in view.xib, you need to insert this line in view.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

Refers above outlet in view.xib and comment out line 35-37 in ViewController.m

And then add the following codes for View *view in **- (void)viewDidLoad {}**

```
    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [view.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    view.collectionView.delegate = self;
    view.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Still please understand that the above recommendations are minimum changes for your current repository and may not be the best practice. There are many things need to be put into consideration and the combination will be very different according to each scenario.

Comment: Yes, that will avoid the crash, but I won't be able to load the nib file (view) I created. And that is my point on this discussion. How do I do it?

Comment: @RafaelNascimento If you would like to load view via nib file. You need to delete the collectionView in xib. I think you need to re-think the relationship between storyboard, xib, file owner, data source and delegate of UICollectionView. They are not connected with right places according to the git repository.

Comment: Ok, I see what u mean. Can u recommend me how to set the right relationship or some material that does so?

Comment: @RafaelNascimento According to requirements for different scenarios, the recommendation will be varied. I'm assuming you prefer to putting collectionView in view.xib. Please take my updated answer for references.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I have the same error but with swift. How can I do it?